# Querying mongo array of embedded documents in aggregation pipeline

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was looking into the different ways of querying on array of embedded documents in aggregation pipeline MongoDB. Looks like MongoDB has less support for this.

Let's say we have following documents in test collection:

```
/* 1 */
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df2c39fbd406137d4290b3"),
    "a" : 1.0,
    "arr" : [ 
        {
           "key": 1,
           "sn" : "a",
           "org": "A"
        }
    ]
   }

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df2c47fbd406137d4290b4"),
    "a" : 2.0,
    "arr" : [ 
        {
            "sn" : "b",
            "key": 2,
            "org": "B"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df2c50fbd406137d4290b5"),
    "a" : 3.0,
    "arr" : [ 
        {

           "key": 3,
           "sn" : "c", 
           "org": "C"
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df2c85fbd406137d4290b6"),
    "a" : 1.0,
    "arr" : [ 
        {
           "key": 1,
           "sn" : "a",
           "org": " A"
        }
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df2c9bfbd406137d4290b7"),
    "a" : 3.0,
    "arr" : [ 
        {
            "sn" : "b",
            "key": 2,
        }
    ]
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df2e41fbd406137d4290b8"),
    "a" : 4.0,
    "arr" : [ 
        {
            "sn" : "b",
            "key" : 2
        }
    ]
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df2e5ffbd406137d4290b9"),
    "a" : 5.0,
    "arr" : [ 
        {
           "key" : 2,
            "sn" : "b"
        }, 
        {
            "sn" : "a",
            "key" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

And I wanted to categorize the above documents based on "arr.sn" field value using below query:

```
db.test.aggregate([{"$addFields": {"Category" : { $switch: {
     branches : [
       { case : { $eq : [ "$arr.nm", "a" ] }, then : "Category 1"}
    ],
    default : "No Category"
    }}}}])
```

but $eq operator is not giving correct result, if I use the same $eq in find method, it works:

```
db.test.find({"arr.sn" : "a"})
```

I am looking at the way to do it with only single field, here in case "arr.sn" field. Is there any way to project the field from embedded documents from the array?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[`$eq(aggregation)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) compares both value and type different from query [`eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) opeator which can compare values for any type.

You need [`$in(aggregation)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to verify value in a array.

Something like

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Category": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$in": [
                  "a",
                  "$arr.sn"
                ]
              },
              "then": "Category 1"
            }
          ],
          "default": "No Category"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks @Veeram for your solution, actually $in operator requires all array fields to be present, however I am looking at the way to do it with only single field, here in case "arr.sn" field. I have modified the array entries in question. Is there any way to project the field from embedded documents from the array?

Comment: Np. I'm not following you. What do you mean by single field ? `arr.sn` returns array of values and `$in` looks for a value in array of values. What did I miss ?

Comment: Your solution works but not in the case where array contains below embedded document                                         
For ex:   arr : [    {
           "key": 1,
           "sn" : "a",
           "org": " A"
        } ].

Comment: In $in clause, I just want to try with  "sn" : "a"

Comment: It works for me in all cases. Not sure why you want to try  sn:a when there is no such syntax in the aggregation query pipeline. In above case arr.sn returns ["a"] and when you do "a" in ["a"] it returns true.

Comment: thanks @veeram for clearing my doubt and posting the answer, I was using below query to do it, which is wrong:                                           db.test.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Category": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$in": [
                  { sn : "a"},
                  "$arr"
                ]
              },
              "then": "Category 1"
            }
          ],
          "default": "No Category"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Comment: Np. Your query will match when you have array entries like `arr : [ { "sn" : "a"} ... ]` i.e when you want to match the whole document in the array.